# How do I put values from a loop in their own DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help for returning the value from the loop. Here is my javascript code :

```
get_images = ["01","02","03"];

for(var i=0; i < get_images.length; i++){

images = '<img src="images/' + page_id + '/gallery/01/' +    get_images[i] +'.jpg"  >';

}

$("#imgs").html(images);
```

What I want is, I want get all the value " images " from inside the loop and put it into inside the

```
<div id="imgs"></div>
```

How do I put the images found in the loop into their own `div` tag?

Comment: I think you are misleading get_images[i] which returns the value 0,1,2 but whereas 01,02,03 you have so place the sample result you want.

Comment: hmmm, get_image is an array and in the loop code I use get_images[i] for get the value of the array get_images ( get_images[0] // 01, get_images[1] // 02,get_images[3] // 03 ). Here what I want is I want get all that value and put into the div with $("#imgs").html(images), but without write get_images[0] // 01, get_images[1] // 02,get_images[3] // 03, Thanks @C-link

Comment: I meant the result like this <img src="images/1/gallery/01/1.jpg"> that you wanted.

Comment: The result will become <img src="images/1/gallery/01/01.jpg">,<img src="images/1/gallery/01/02.jpg">,<img src="images/1/gallery/01/03.jpg">, Thanks

Comment: So you need to do like this: '<img src="images/' + page_id + '/gallery/01/0' +    get_images[i] +'.jpg"  >'

Comment: But if I do like <img src="images/' + page_id + '/gallery/01/0' + get_images[i] +'.jpg" >, the output will become <img src="images/1/gallery/01/001.jpg">, so here is the explanation, for get_images[0] the result become 01, and get_images[1] become 02 and get_images[2] become 03, from loop the result is <img src="images/1/gallery/01/01.jpg">,<img src="images/1/gallery/01/02.jpg"> and <img src="images/1/gallery/01/03.jpg"> now I want add those value into the div where I get the value from variable " images " inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
get_images = ["01","02","03"];
var images ='',
    arrLength = get_images.length;
for(var i=0; i < arrLength; i++){
// Here concatenate your values.
images += '<img src="images/' + page_id + '/gallery/01/' +    get_images[i] +'.jpg"  >';

}

$("#imgs").html(images);
```

Comment: But i have 'undefined' in the first loop, do you know what is about???here is the log undefined<img src="images/11/gallery/01/01.jpg"  ><img src="images/11/gallery/01/02.jpg"  ><img src="images/11/gallery/01/03.jpg"  >, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to do string append? Right now you're overwriting the images variable in every iteration:

```
images = images  + '<img src="images/' + page_id + '/gallery/01/' +    get_images[i] +'.jpg"  >';
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, what I mean is I want get all the value from the loop and I add into div, it solve already , Thanks :)